# Android Benchmark module - How to test application

Tags: android, performance, testing, kotlin, benchmarking

I have created a new benchmark module in my application to test out performance of my cide.

My Project Structure is like this

```
Project_name
-app
-benchmark
```

app is Android application (com.android.application) while benchmark module is library (com.android.library).

I want to test my Java/Kotlin code as well as performance of my xml's inside my app module.
Now in benchmark samples https://github.com/android/performance-samples the module being benchmarked is a library module.

How can I refer my Java/Kotlin files and my xml's inside my benchmark module to test the performance.

Note: I tried putting benchmark tests in the app module but it does not calculate the speed of the methods/layout inflation if used outside benchmark module.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle does not support a library module to be dependent on an application module. The only solution I came up with is to move just everything from `app` to a library module (call it, for example, `main`), so the app module contains only `AndroidManifest.xml` and gradle configuration. This way `benchmark` can depend on the `main` module.